# Roll the file over using Log::Log4perl

Tags: perl

I am using the
[`Log::Log4perl`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Log::Log4perl)
module to capture log data. After midnight I am trying to roll the file over from `count.log` to `count.log.1` in write mode, but I am not able to do so.

Below is the logfile info:

```
log4perl.rootLogger               = INFO, myFILE
log4perl.appender.myFILE          = Log::Dispatch::FileRotate
log4perl.appender.myFILE.filename = /user/Desktop/Records.log
log4perl.appender.myFILE.max      = 4
log4perl.appender.myFILE.mode     = write
log4perl.appender.myFILE.DatePattern = yyyy-MM-dd
log4perl.appender.myFILE.TZ       = UTC
log4perl.appender.myFILE.layout   = PatternLayout
#log4perl.appender.myFILE.layout.ConversionPattern = %d %m %n
#log4perl.appender.myFILE.layout.ConversionPattern = %m %n
log4perl.appender.myFILE.layout.ConversionPattern = [%d] [%F:%L] [%p %c] %m%n
```

Comment: Your config file says you are logging to `/user/Desktop/Records.log` but your question says `count.log`. Which is it?

Comment: Hey sorry for the mistake, its Records.log only